# Mapping of Interface is Not Supported, But Linq-Sql Object Already Implements Property

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, interface, linq-expressions

So, I created a DataContext (Linq-Sql) in VS from an existing database. It has a table called Users, thus I have a `User` object. In particular, I want to focus on the `UserID` and `Username` properties.

Now, I have an interface:

```
interface IUser
{
     int Id { get; }
     string Username { get; }
}
```

I want to create a partial `User` class and implement `IUser`. The reason for this is so that I can treat any User as an IUser in many places and not be concerned about the precise User class:

```
public partial class User : IUser
{
    public int Id
    {
         get { return UserID; }
    }
}
```

I don't implement the `Username` get property because I know that the entity object already implements it.

When I have a query like `dc.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == 5);` I know that it's an error because it'll translate that call to an SQL statement and it's going to try to find the `Id` column, which doesn't exist - UserID exists. So I understand this mapping issue.

When I query `dc.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Username == "admin")`, it also throws an error, BUT `Username` IS indeed an existing column in the database, so my impression is that no custom/additional mapping needs to take place. What am I missing?

Can someone point me to a good source on how to combat Linq vs. partial classes implement a custom interface?

**Update Question:**
Before I try it, does anyone know if "rigging" the datacontext.designer.cs file with our custom interfaces (to implement to the classes themselves instead of in a separate partial class file) will work? Is there a consequence of doing this?

Comment: What error do you receive for `dc.Users.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Username == "admin")` It should work, assuming that Username is a "normal" mapped property.

Comment: I know. It shouldn't, but just because Username is a member of an interface, it complains: The mapping of interface member IUser.Username is not supported.

Comment: I understand now. What static type is `p` in that lambda? What is the static type of `dc.Users`?

Comment: dc.Users I think is System.Data.Linq.Table<User>. and p would be a User, the generic parameter type of the table. I don't know how that would help, though.

Comment: Because LINQ complains that you have used `IUser.Username`. Why would it think that? It seems to be a bug: http://goneale.com/2009/07/22/the-mapping-of-interface-member-is-not-supported/ (But you do understand that you cannot expect LINQ to understand interface members, right? They are not mapped.)

Answer (score 6):

I've come across this before using Generics and LINQ, and the way I solved it was to change `p.Id == 5` to `p.Id.Equals(5)` and LINQ was able to map the query.

In regards to rigging autogenerated code, I have done this in my projects, the only annoyance is having to type all the interfaces again if you regenerate your DBML file. I looked in to dynamically adding interfaces to classes and found this SO post, but I haven't tried it out yet:

[What is the nicest way to dynamically implement an interface in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134270/what-is-the-nicest-way-to-dynamically-implement-an-interface-in-c)

Either way, re-typing is a much better trade off for us right now as we've been able to remove a lot of duplication in our implementation code with this method.

Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough with LINQ or .NET to explain why `Equals()` works when `==` does not :)